# Excel AND Condition to be based on the results of a MATCH Query

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

So, I've got two tables on one sheet (call them `table1` and `table2`) which are split at row 1128.
I have the following statement to see if a value in the B column of `table2` exists in the B column of `table1`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B1161,$B$2:$B$1128,0),"yes",),"no")
```

While this is fairly standard, I want this to return a value based on the accumulative results on:

1. If the value in `table2` exists in `table1` (this is the match query above) **AND**
2. If (in the row of data it found a match in table1) the value of table1's column J is equal to table2's column K in the row I'm performing the query.

Is this possible?

I have come out with this so far, but I don't know how to link the second match by saying "Look in the row in which you found that last bit of data":

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH(B1133,$B$2:$B$1128,0),SecondClauseHere),"yes",),"no")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you give a sample excel file or something more to work with at the moment

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this (to be entered somewhere in row 1161)

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX($J$2:$J$1128,MATCH(B1161,B$2:$B$1128,0)),"")=K1161,"yes","no")
```

but if you have empty cells in the data it may be necessary to change "" to some other value that doesn't occur like (say) 9E99.

If you wanted to tell if it was matched, unmatched or missing you would need

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX($J$2:$J$1128,MATCH(B1161,B$2:$B$1128,0))=K1161,"yes","no"),"Missing")
```